# Trying to figure out the price elasticity of demand

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

I have a demand curve $y(x) = x^{-b}$ where $b > 1$.

I'm trying to figure *the price elasticity of demand*, but I'm not familiar with finding price elasticity without having some sort of numbers.

Normally, I would go about this by taking the partial derivative of the demand curve, but the format is throwing me off?

I think the partial derivative in question $-b*x^{-b-1}$, but I'm having trouble here.

Does anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: Which trouble? That's correct so far (except that "partial" is not needed). Since the $x$-elasticity of $y$ is defined as $\epsilon=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{x}{y}$, you just substitute your derivative in this expression, replace $y$ by $x^{-b}$, and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Price elasticity of demand is defined as:

$$e=\frac{dQ}{dP} \frac{P}{Q}$$

For demand curve $y=x^{-b}$ elasticity of demand is given by

$$e=-b$$